# Every prime ideal is maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Problem: Show that if R is a finite ring, then every prime ideal of R is maximal.

My attempt: Let I be a prime ideal of R. Then, by definition of a prime ideal, ab ∈ I implies a ∈ I or b ∈ I for every a, b ∈ R. Since R is a finite ring, there exists an ideal J such that I ⊆ J ⊆ R.

Question: Please help me on this. The definition of a maximal ideal is as follows: "The ideal I is said to be a **maximal ideal** of R if for all ideals J of R such that I ⊆ J ⊆ R, either J=I or J=R."

I have to apply the fact that R is a finite ring. But I don't know how I can satisfy I ⊆ J ⊆ R...

Comment: What are the characterisations of prime and maximal ideals in terms of $R/I$?

Comment: Should I show that R / I is a field? Then (by a proposition in my textbook) I is a maximal ideal of R.

Answer (score 2):

I can sketch a proof, then you can make all the details: Suppose $I$ is a prime ideal   $\Rightarrow$ $\frac {R}{I}$ is a domain. Notice that every finite domain is a field then  $\frac{R}{I}$ is a field so ${I}$ is maximal.